# Expand viewing window of excel drop down list. 2007/2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

please see image for what i am trying to accomplish. what i would like to do is with this drop down list that is created, i would like to expand the viewing window to twice as large as it currently is. so instead of seeing 8 names, i would like to see 16 (or more) names at a time.

is this possible?

Comment: The clear answer is: No, it cannot be changed! :-( There are a few tweaks to change the width - see [this link](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal08.html#Font) but no way to change the lenght. You'd need an ActiveX element instead.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing works for **filter options list**, but not for in-cell dropdowns - I think this may NOT be done via "pure" Excel UI features.

However, this info: [Expanding the size of the in-cell dropdown list](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/677241-expanding-the-size-of-the-in-cell-dropdown-list.html) - might be helpful if a bit of coding is an option for you.